# Uzo de ĉar + A-vorto

Tags: word-usage

Iafoje mi trovas la jenan uzon de *ĉar*, kiu al mi unuavide ŝajnas fremda:

> 1) Ankoraŭ ne aŭdita, ĉar eksterordinara. [PIV]
>
> 2) Ĝi fariĝis do vivanta, ĉar uzata. [Vivo de Zamenhof, de Edmond
>   Privat]
>
> 3) Ĉar stulta, mi neniam guton da vino provis. [La lasta deziro, de
>   Josip Velebit]
>
> 4) Li estas pardonebla, ĉar juna. [Granda Vortaro Hispana-Esperanta]

La subkomprenataj vortoj estas *pronomo + esti*:

1) ĉar *ĝi estas* eksterordinara

2) ĉar *ĝi estas* uzata

3) ĉar *mi estas* stulta

4) ĉar *li estas* juna

En PMEG troviĝas klarigo pri se + I-verbo:

*se preni la plej malmulte = se oni prenu la plej malmulte*

*se lin kompari kun... = se oni lin komparu kun...*

*se paroli sincere = se mi parolu sincere...*

*se tiel diri = se oni povus tiel diri*

Sed pri la uzo de *ĉar + A-vorto* mi nenion trovis. Ĉu ekzistas ia regulo aŭ klarigo pri tia uzo de *ĉar*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La artikolo en PIV pri "ĉar" indikas ke "ĉar" povas esti uzata elipse, kaj donas la jenan ekzemplon:

- junul’ freneza, ĉar ambrula

Krome mi trovis kelkajn aliajn ekzemplojn en Monato.

- sed tiu ne estas atingebla, ĉar okupata.
- kio fakte ne ekzistas ĉar virtuala.
- la entreprenaj rezultoj estas sufiĉe certaj, ĉar antaŭkalkuleblaj.

Comment: Ho! Ĉar neatenta, mi tute mistrafis tiun ekzemplon en PIV. Dankon por la atentigo.